# WPF ScrollViewer starts scrolling to early

Tags: wpf, xaml, width, scrollviewer, minimum

I need a way to make a button overlap a textblock when resizing horizontally to a smaller size.This works fine for the first example, but when i put the same code in a scrollviewer, the horizontal scrollbar kicks in from the moment the textblock and button meet.
How can i avoid this so that the button overlaps the same way as without the scrollviewer? Ideally scrolling should start from the moment that the textblock reaches its minimum width.

```
      <StackPanel>
            <!--works-->
            <Grid Height="30" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="20">te</Button>
            </Grid>

            <!--doesn't work-->
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <Grid Height="30" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="20">te</Button>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
```

**Update**
In fact i can reduce the problem to a textblock in a scrollviewer. I would like that it would only become possible for the horizontal scrollbar to scroll when the min width of the textblock is reached.

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TextBlock Background="Yellow" 
                   MinWidth="50">reallylooooooooooooooooooooong 
                   text</TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**Update**
I found a solution here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26e03045-4b57-4960-8d33-d0295855f4e3/minwidth-with-scrollviewer-to-then-take-over?forum=wpf
The converter substracts the width of the button from the actual width of the grid.Now it starts scrolling the moment that the minimum width of the textblock is reached.

I don't know if a custom scrollviewer for any content could be smart enough to behave the same way?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            >
    <Grid Height="30" x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"  
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                MinWidth="150"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualWidth, 
                 Converter={x:Static conv:WidthConverter.Instance}}"
                ></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="20">te</Button>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: just a shot in the dark: `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Visible` forces the scrollbar to be shown, doesn't is? tried with `Auto`?

Comment: Doesn't help. The main problem is that the button doesn't move over the textblock when resizing to a smaller size when used in a scrollviewer. But then at some point the scrollbar has to kick in(when content width is bigger than scrollviewer width). Now this starts when button and textblock hit each other, but this should be when textblock has reached minimum width.

Comment: get rid of the stackpanel in your second code... Why do you need it in first place? If you want to insert multiple instances of your 'Grid', then use an `ItemsControl` panel *inside* your `scrollviewer`

Comment: I don't need to show multiple elements governed by a scrollviewer. I need the stackpanel with scrollviewer to work the same as the one without the scrollviewer. If you would drop my code in a test project you would see how the stackpanel with scrollviewer behaves differently than the stackpanel without

Comment: If I hand't put your code to a test project, I couldn't post an answer... So, why you need to stick with the Stackpanel for a single element....?. Maybe you could describe your goal in a broader scope...

Comment: @ dba I do agree that a stackpanel for a single element isn't needed. I'll update the question. The final goal is a tabcontrol that behaves similar to google chrome tabs, where the close button moves over the page title when resizing, And when arrived at minimum size , the left right scroll buttons become visible.

Comment: Referencing the converter as a static instance will create rooted object, which the garbage collector won't be able to collect for the lifetime of the application. To allow memory management for this object, better create a resource that you can reference using `StaticResource`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show multiple elements in a panel, governed by a scrollviewer you may use an `ItemsControl` inside the `ScrollViewer`

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
      <ItemsControl >
        <Grid Height="30">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
          <Button Grid.Column="1"
                  MinWidth="20">te</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="30">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
          <Button Grid.Column="1"
                  MinWidth="20">te</Button>
        </Grid>
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I don't need to show multiple elements governed by a scrollviewer. I need the grid with scrollviewer to work the same as the one without the scrollviewer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to re-template the ScrollViewer control. Start by extracting the template by moving the cursor over the ScrollViewer control and from the Properties pane select Miscellaneous -> Template -> Convert To New Resource (from the drop-down). The ScrollContentPresenter in the new template that appears is what draws everything inside the "client area":

```
<ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanVerticallyScroll="False" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

So move your 2-column grid from outside the template to that point there, and move the ScrollContentPresenter to it's left column and your button to it's  right. You should also set the button's column width to "Auto" so that it gets all the space it needs. Final ControlTemplate should look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanVerticallyScroll="False" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="20">te</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And your XAML should look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerTemplate1}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid Height="30" >
            <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code but the scrollbar started scrolling a bit to early, needed to be at the minimum width of the textblock. I found a solution on msdn.

Comment: @Jan *"... needed to be at the minimum width of the textblock"* - but then the user is unable to read the text that is clipped by the button. That's a very odd requirement. Shouldn't the text be readable all the time? Shouldn't the scroll bar appear as soon as text got clipped?

Comment: @BionicCode. Google chrome tabs also clippes the text by the button. And then at the right hand side, there is a button that shows a list where you can see all items (text) at larger size

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the complete `Grid` into a `ScrollViewer` results in the `ScrollViewer` to make all its contained elements visible i.e. scrollable. In your case, it will make the `TextBlock` and the `Button` scrollable.

To allow the `Button` to clip the `TextBlock` i.e. the `TextBlock.Text` to virtually exceed the actual width of the `TextBlock`, you can wrap the `TextBlock` alone into a `ScrollViewer`.
This will result in the `TextBlock` being able to hide or clip text that exceeds the available rendering width, while the user can still view it entirely by scrolling.

The following example will make the scroll bars appear as soon text has become hidden from the user, allowing him to still read all the text:

```xml
<Grid Height="30">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf" />
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Button Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          MinWidth="20">te</Button>
</Grid>
```

---

Your requirement sounds like you want to hide certain amount of text from the user before he is allowed to scroll through it, enabling him to read all the text.
From a user experience point of view, I highly recommend against such a behavior.
However, to achieve this, simply modify the above example to add a negative right `Padding` to the `ScrollViewer`:

```xml
<Grid Height="30">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                Padding="0,0,-150,0>
    <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf" />
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Button Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          MinWidth="20">te</Button>
</Grid>
```

---

The above solution will clip the exceeding text and will show a `ScrollViewer` after a certain threshold (controlled via `ScrollViewer.Padding`), but will not allow to scroll the entire hidden text (only the portion from the moment on the `ScrollViewer` became visible).

To enable scrolling of the entire hidden text, you can define a simple `Style` that resets the `Padding` to `0` (in fact, it will toggle the `Padding`), once the scroll bars are visible:

```xml
<Grid Height="30">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition /n>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ScrollViewer.Style>

      <!-- Optionally, move this Style to a ResourceDictionary (e.g. App.xaml), 
           to make it apply to all ScrollViewer instance within the scope -->
      <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="0,0,-150,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                   Value="Visible">
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="0" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Style>

    <TextBlock Text="testsdfqqsdfqsdqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfqsdfsdqsdf" />
  </ScrollViewer>

  <Button Grid.Column="1"
          MinWidth="20">te</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: According to the author (who is a colleague, hence the bounty), your answer does not give a full answer to his needs, but he agreed according you the bounty.

Comment: Sorry, but I found the requirement difficult to understand. I tried my best to address the problem as I understood it, but apparently I didn't understand it well enough. If you like to share more details and why this solution does not help you to solve the problem, I can probably improve my answer to make it more helpful.